# Why CRC seed is called polynomial?

Tags: crc

Why is CRC seed is called polynomial?  Is their any significance in related to the CRC algorithm by calling it a polynomial?  Can't we just say n bits random binary number.

Comment: I did more research and so far found that there is mathematical background for finding good seed value that detect most errors.
Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Designing_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Think of the bits in a `CRC` of `N` bits as the coefficients of a polynomial of degree `N-1`.  So the if we had a CRC of `1101`  that would be `x^3 + x^2 + 1`.  Usually they are much larger.  And when working with message digests and similar algorithms, the texts on which they are applied are also considered polynomials of extremely high degree.  It is simply a way of looking at them that lends itself to mathematical analysis.

Comment: I deleted my prior comment. I will delete this one later.